# SCIP - Integral separation

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, scip

I developed a SCIP/MIP model using LP relaxation which relies on branching on 0-1 variables. However, it is quite inefficient as I have not figured out how to use relevant SCIP callbacks. 
Here is my code:

```
isMIP = False
while True:
    model.optimize()
    if isMIP:
        print("Optimal value:", model.getObjVal())
        break
    else:
        print("Intermediate value:", model.getObjVal())

    x,y,u = model.data
    fracvars = []
    for j in y:
        w = model.getVal(y[j])
        if w > 0.001 and w < 0.999:
            fracvars.append([j,abs(w-0.5)])
    if fracvars:
        fracvars.sort(key = itemgetter(1))
        min_var, min_value = min([(val[0],val[1]) for val in fracvars])
        model.freeTransform()
        model.chgVarType(y[min_var],"I") # the very inefficient part...
        print("Integer constraint on y[%s]" % min_var)
    else:
        isMIP = True
```

Could anyone help me speed up the code? Many thanks.

Comment: why don't you add integrality restrictions to all integer variables from the start and let SCIP solve the problem directly?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. SCIP will solve your model if you just call `optimize()`. You do not need to implement your own branching, simply declare your variables to be binary when building the model.

Comment: you're both right as y is declared as a variable in my problem. However I especially wanted to know how to separate on y using SCIP internal functions if y was a linear constraint and not a declared variable. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please see http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/BRANCH.php for how to write a branching rule and http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/SEPA.php for cutting plane separators (I am still not sure what you want to do exactly...). This is the description for C plugins, but the equivalents should exist in PySCIPOpt or should be easy to add if you know what you need.